# How to improve my script and copy program resources on build?

Tags: c++, cmake, copy, resources

So I got into a problem where I needed to use linux for a while instead of windows, and figured linux doesn't have Visual Studio. I then also realized that I made my project Visual Studio only, which I don't want.

So I looked up some CMake tutorials and try'ed creating some examples that could be loaded in both Visual Studio and CodeBlocks. When I got that to work, I went and code a CMake script for my actual program by piecing together what I learned and what I found in tutorials.
See here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

add_subdirectory(libraries/glfw)

project (OpenGLEngine3D)

include_directories(libraries/glfw/include)
include_directories(libraries/glm)
include_directories(libraries/glad/include)
include_directories(libraries/whereami/src)
include_directories(libraries/stb)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h" "libraries/whereami/src/whereami.c" "libraries/glad/src/glad.c")

add_executable(OpenGLEngine3D  ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(OpenGLEngine3D glfw)
```

Its dirty(I think) but it works.
So now my **first** question is, how to improve my CMake script? What is redundant or done in a poor way?

Now my program also requires some resources(like shaders, textures) which I have stored in a directory along with my CMake script, libraries and c++ files.
So my **second** question is, how would I tell CMake to the ide/compiler to copy the files in a certain directory to the program build directory(where the compiled binaries are) after compiling?(And have it only do it when the files aren't there ofc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across [this article](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/), which might be help you with CMake.

Here are a couple suggestions from me:

1. You're safe to use newer version of CMake. Currently, it's 3.11. There's no point in sticking to old versions.
2. Consider listing all your sources in a variable (using [`set` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/set.html)) instead of using `file(GLOB)`. `file(GLOB)` will be evaluated only once, when generating build files. If you add new sources, you'll have to re-generate it manually, so it doesn't help too much, and is harder to debug (and really, debugging more complex CMake projects can be painful).
3. Avoid using `include_directories` (and `link_libraries`). Prefer using `target_include_directories` which works per-target. It allows to express dependencies between targets (when you have more than one - which might happen as your project grows)
4. You might consider using `find_package(GLFW)`, instead of including GLFW in your project. **Edit:** actually, CMake doesn't came with find module for GLFW, but you can use an external module for this (e. g. [this one](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk-m/blob/783867eeb05e0a6538f9c520af02c3615651b4ed/CMake/FindGLFW.cmake)) as described [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries).

**Edit:**

Example below illustrates the idea behind point 2), assuming that sources are placed in "src/" directory on the same level as `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(engine_sources
    "src/header_1.hpp"
    "src/source_1.cpp"
    # and so on for reset of files...
)

add_executable(OpenGLEngine3D ${engine_sources})
```

---

As for the second question: that's what [`file(COPY)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/file.html) is for. Alternatively, you could just leave assets in source directory, and set working directory in IDE.

Side note: if you choose the second options, there appears to be a way to set this from CMake for Visual Studio, by setting [`VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY.html) property:

```
set_target_properties(OpenGLEngine3D PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

*(I haven't checked if this works as expected, as I rarely use VS. I remember looking for something like that in the past, and just recently came across it.)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How would I put the sources and headers in a variable? I thought file(glob source) was a variable?

Comment: I've added an example, hopefully illustrates the idea well.

Comment: But then I need to enter ALL of my files? That are like 50 files, and I keep adding new. Isn't it better to use the way I currently did it?(As I otherwise have to manually edit the CMake file every time?)

Comment: When using `file(GLOB)` you still have to manually regenerate build files - CMake won't check if new files were added, so I'd say that both approaches have similar overhead. I suggested listing files verbatim, because this way because: a) it more clear what actually gets compiled and b) you can easily choose what is compiled in CMake (e. g. you could conditionally add platform dependent sources based on value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`). But this is a subjective thing - if `file(GLOB)` works for you, just use it.